# Key in same table in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a hireiarchial table in postgres. I'm using the adjacent list-approach. My question is, how should I reference the ID of the same table when creating the data-model?

```
create table nodes (
    id serial primary key,
    parentid WHAT GOES HERE?
    name varchar,
);
```

Comment: `parentid INTEGER REFERENCES nodes(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
create table nodes (
    id serial primary key,
    parentid integer references nodes(id),
    name varchar
);
```

These are called "self-referencing tables"